# SharePoint 2007 - setting column to list creator's full name or email? Lookup site user properties?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, user-profile, user-profile-property

We installed this codeplex soluiton and activiated in one of our web aps. We are on sp2007 SP2.

http://sharepointapplied.com/2009/01/08/get-full-name-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow/#comment-419

In SPD, I add a new workflow and am able to add the action for lookup site user property.. but nothing happens.